# Which one is correct presentation for descriptive statistic of a transformed variable between retransformed mean (estimated SD), and median (qurtiles)

Tags: standard-deviation, back-transformation

If a collected variable has a skewed distribution toward one side and transformed for statistical analysis, which one is better for descriptive statistics presentation between re-transformed mean and SD, and median (1st quartile - 3rd quartile)?

Usually, for the statistical analysis, several variable transformation methods like log, exponential or Box-cox power transformation are required. Then, I understand the interpretation and presentation of statistical results should follow the re-transforamtion rules, it is quietly different from the case of analysis with not-transformed variables. However, in this case, should I present the descriptive statistics (mean and standard deviation) for this variable as a re-transformed form? Many thanks in advance to whom give me an adequate answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends how you want to use the descriptive statistics and depending on the practice in your field.

For example, in economics where I come from it’s not unusual for people to report descriptives on log of total assets, equity or some other variables. It depends on what purpose you want to use your descriptive statistics for. If the purpose is to just give some information on the moments of variables you use in your subsequent analysis then I would say you don’t need to retransform it back. If you want to use it for some argument where the actual values are interesting then you should.

A good idea would be also to look at related research in your field because practice may differ between fields.

Comment: Thank you for clear opinion. Actually, I'm in the medical fields. In this field, descriptive statistics provide information about collected data and could be used as an expected value for future data gathering like power calculation.